# How to convert Excel (XLSXWriter) file to PDF in Python

Tags: python, excel, pdf, xlsxwriter, in-memory

I have created an xlsx file in memory (BytesIO) with the help of the XLSXWriter Library. I now want to read that in-memory file and convert it into pdf format, and the result should also be a bytes object.
Which library and how can I achieve this result? I'm facing trouble finding any Python library that might help me achieve this.

I have tried to find different solutions but all in vain.

Comment: what did you try? What modules did you try? You could show your code. Maybe you made small mistake and it could work with small fix. Put information in question, not in comments. It will be more readable and more peole may see it - so more people may help. BTW: if you get error message then also show FULL error message in question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.